# ElasticSearch / Kibana timestamp - field or _source?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-7

My single raw document in ES/Kibana looks like this:

```
{
  "_index": "fluentd.apache.access.20191202",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "8jql724B3OrCHx56JnWb",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "serveraddress": "....",
    "clientaddress": "...",
    "@timestamp": "2019-12-02T11:00:30+0000",
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "....",
    "status": 200,
    "bytes": 19820,
    "referrer": "....",
    "agent": "...",
    "@log_name": "apache.access"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2019-12-02T11:00:30.000Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

Why do the `@timestamp`s differ regarding their format?

```
2019-12-02T11:00:30+0000 (UTC timezone, no milliseconds)
2019-12-02T11:00:30.000Z (milliseconds + "Z" for UTC timezone)
```

What does my index mapping have to look like to have the time quickfilter available in Discover?

Currently it looks like this and it doesn't show me the timespan quickfilter:

```
...,
"@timestamp": {
  "type": "date",
  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
},
...
```

Index pattern:

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you created your index pattern, which date field did you pick? That's the field that will be used by the time picker in the Discover view.

Comment: @Val see the screenshot

Comment: It doesn't look like you picked the `@timestamp` field when creating that index pattern otherwise there would be a small hour clock showing next to its name. See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns.html#_manage_your_index_pattern)

Comment: @Val there is clock symbol in the Discover view and Kibana seems to understand the format: <clocksymbol> @ timestamp Dec 2, 2019 @ 12:00:30.000

Comment: No it just means it's a date field, but it's not THE date field

Comment: Go ahead, create a new index pattern that matches your fluentd indexes and pick the `@timestamp` field as THE time field and you'll see the difference

Comment: @Val Yea! That worked! I had a lot back and forth and recreating the index pattern solved the problem! Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recreate the index pattern and make sure to select the `@timestamp` field as THE time field for that index pattern.

That's the field Kibana uses for selecting documents based on the time selected int he time picker.